# Can't get response using iron-form in google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, polymer-1.0

I have implemented a form using iron-form and I am able to process it in the server, but then I can't figure out how to get the response out, I cannot redirect to another page or refresh. If I remove the 'is="iron-form' then it works fine. I'm using polymer 1.0, google app engine, and jinja2 for templating.

HTML:

```
<div class="c-form">
    <h1>"Contact us"</h1>
    <p> {{ sucess-message }} </p>
    <form is="iron-form" id="contact-form" method="post" action="/formhandler">
        <paper-input label="Name" name="name" required></paper-input>
        <paper-textarea label="Message" name="msj" required></paper-textarea>
        <paper-button raised class="colorful" onclick="submitForm()">Send</paper-button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();
    }
</script>
```

main.py:

```
class FormHandler(MainHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.name = self.request.get('name')
        self.msj = self.request.get('msj')
        mesj = MensajesDB.new_msj(self.name, self.msj)
        mesj.put()
        self.respose.out.write("SUCCESS")   //Here I would like to render the template, 
                                            but I can't get it to render or redirect to 
                                            another page...

class MainPage(MainHandler):
def get(self):
    self.render("home.html", route="home", title="Home")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
('/formhandler', FormHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `self.render` like in your `MainPage` handler?

Comment: Yes, I tried but the page does not get reloaded. Looking through the code  for iron-form I think the iron-form prevents the page from reloading unless I do something, but I don't know what that something is...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be having trouble debugging where the failure is happening. I suggest familiarizing yourself with the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) -- specifically, the Network tab, which will allow you to monitor the requests from your JS to your server, and then the server responses.

From your server-side application, you can access the entire request body from within your `FormHandler.post` method using the `self.request.POST` variable, [as documented here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#post-data).

If you want to redirect after saving to the Datastore, you'll need to remove the `self.response.out.write()` line and use [`self.redirect()`](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html?highlight=redirect#webapp2.redirect) instead.  Note that you cannot send a response body/string **and** redirect in a single response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely give it a try!

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck and let me know if it helps to solve your issue.